# Encoding problems with cmd or Power Shell or both

Tags: windows, powershell, encoding, cmd

All I need is copy text as `text/html` into clipboard by CLI and then paste it into rich text editor on `utf-8` web page. But there are encoding problems with cyryllic characters - despite using `chcp` to change encoding.

This is how .ps1 file looks like (Of course file itself have UTF-8 encoding too):

```
 chcp 65001
 $args[0] | Set-Clipboard -AsHtml
```

Run script from cmd with `chcp 65001(UTF-8)` and cyrillic parameter:

```
 chcp 65001
 powershell C:\Users\admin\go.ps1 "КИРИЛЛИЦА IS CYRILLIC"
```

Command output:

[image]

The problem is here when I paste into rich text editor I get:

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `-AsHtml`?

Comment: Because I need copy text as "text/html" format and then paste it into rich text box

Comment: Why?  That's the cause of your problem.

Comment: For pasting as rich text. Does it really matter?

Yes, I see, without "-AsHtml" all working fine. But is there way to put cyrillic text in clipboard as html?

Comment: The console codepage (set by chcp.com) is irrelevant. CMD reads Unicode from the console via `ReadConsoleW` and calls `CreateProcessW` to spawn PowerShell, which in turn reads and parses the Unicode command line. The problem is simply the `-AsHtml` option.

Comment: Okay, but without this option all is pointless. So it`s not possible to copy cyrillic symbols as text/html?

Comment: Why are you trying to?  Without knowing, there's no way to help you besides saying what you're trying isn't going to work/doesn't work, obviously.

Comment: In my case paste text is the fastest way. Emulating keyboard input too slow and assign text to form isn`t possible.
Sorry, but can you answer my question - is it possible to copy cyrillic characters as text/html?
maybe without Power shell, node.js or .exe file which can be runned with parametrs?

Answer (score 1):

[BUG: `Set-Clipboard -AsHtml` puts invalid `CF_HTML` on clipboard with non-ASCII text](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/17727688-bug-set-clipboard-ashtml-puts-invalid-cf-html-on)

[Blake Coverett](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/users/307215574-blake-coverett)'s workaround, *for anyone else bitten by this*:

```
Function StringToEntities ($aux) {
  ## https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/users/307215574-blake-coverett
    ($aux.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object { 
        $codePoint = [int]$_ 
        if ($codePoint -ge 127) { 
            "&#$codePoint;" 
        } else { 
            $_ 
        } 
    }) -join ''
}

'buggy'
$args[0] | Set-Clipboard -AsHtml
Get-Clipboard -TextFormatType Html | Where-Object {$_ -match 'body'}
'workaround'
StringToEntities( $args[0]) | Set-Clipboard -AsHtml
Get-Clipboard -TextFormatType Html | Where-Object {$_ -match 'body'}
```

**Sample output** (merely for debugging; shows that `cmd` code page does not matter):

```
==> chcp
Active code page: 852

==> powershell -noprofile D:\PShell\SO\47474346.ps1 "'КИРИЛЛИЦА IS CYRILLIC, ελληνικά is Greek'"

buggy
<html><body><!--StartFragment-->????????? IS CYRILLIC, ???????? is Greek<!--EndFragment--></body
></html>
workaround
<html><body><!--StartFragment-->&#1050;&#1048;&#1056;&#1048;&#1051;&#1051;&#1048;&#1062;&#1040;
IS CYRILLIC, &#949;&#955;&#955;&#951;&#957;&#953;&#954;&#940; is Greek<!--EndFragment--></body><
/html>

==>
```

Tested at https://html-online.com/editor/:

[image: pasted HTML clipboard]